# Programatically change element's offset based on it's own size and current offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a test layout like below

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

i need all offsets to increase or decrease when the element's size changes.
so i tried it on Hover function in CSS3 like this.

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform-origin: center top;        /* which origin to scale from */
}
#child:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

Everything seems alright but I need a way of achieving the same thing using JavaScript or jQuery but basing all calculations on the exact element not it's parent since an handling dynamic content.

Comment: Try to write some code then we can give feedback. We don't want to write all your code.

Comment: @sumit, Thanks for getting back to me but by pragmatically i meant without using css but the updated answer is pretty much the same as the first one since you are handing over the same style properties to the element.